# Batch file to move files from one FTP folder to another folder in the same FTP?

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, ftp, transfer

Good morning all,

I have a task where i need to automate a process where we download files from an FTP site, the files are processed in SQL, and then the files on the FTP site are moved to another folder on that same FTP site.

The first two parts i have down but the part of moving the files on the FTP to another folder on the same FTP is tripping me up.

Can anyone please offer some advice?

This is what i currently have:

```
@Echo Off
Set _FTPServerName=SERVER HERE
Set _UserName=LOGIN HERE
Set _Password=PASSWORD HERE
Set _RemoteFolder=FILES FROM
Set _NewRemoteFolder=FILES TO
Set _Filename=*.*
Set _ScriptFile=ftp1

:: Create script
"%_ScriptFile%" Echo open %_FTPServerName%
"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_UserName%
"%_ScriptFile%" Echo %_Password%
"%_ScriptFile%" Echo cd %_RemoteFolder%
"%_ScriptFile%" prompt

:: Run script
ftp -s:"%_ScriptFile%"
Del "%_ScriptFile%"
```

Please let me know if you have further questions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [`rename` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftp-rename) in Windows `ftp.exe` command-line client:

```
rename oldname newname
```

---

So in your specific batch file:

```
"%_ScriptFile%" echo rename file.txt %_NewRemoteFolder%/file.txt
```

---

Though seeing the `_Filename=*.*` in your question, it actually looks like you want to move all files. That's not possible with Windows `ftp.exe`, at least not easily. The `rename` command does not support wildcards.

You would have to dynamically generate a script file based on a list of downloaded files with a separate `rename` command for each file.

---

Or use a different command-line FTP client that supports wildcards when renaming/moving.

For example with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) the batch file would be like:

```
winscp.com /log=winscp.log /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@example.com" ^
    "cd %_RemoteFolder%" ^
    "mv *.* %_NewRemoteFolder%/" ^
    "exit"
```

For details see:

- [`mv` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_mv)
- [Converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP FTP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp)

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Hey @Martin Prikryl Thank you so much for your response! I just wanted to say i used another article of yours using WinSCP to help with another thing i was testing and it was phenominal, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way to handle this is to use PowerShell. This will make the file copy happen on the FTP host without requiring the data to come to your client before being written back to the server.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName FTPHOST -ScriptBlock { Move-Item -Path C:\dir1\thefile.txt -Destination C:\dir2\thefile.txt }
```

You can run this from a cmd.exe shell.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "Invoke-Command -ComputerName FTPHOST -ScriptBlock { Move-Item -Path C:\dir1\thefile.txt -Destination C:\dir2\thefile.txt }"
```

Comment: Hey @lit thank you so much for your response. Do you know if PowerShell is something that comes pre-installed or is it something that would need to be installed and configured?

Comment: Also, is that code you provided, would that be executable inside a batch file?

Comment: I believe that PowerShell comes pre-installed on Windows 10 and Server 2012. You may have to configure PowerShell remoting.

Comment: How does this connect to the FTP service on the server? Where does the authentication go?

Comment: @lit that is amazing, thankyou! IOU 1 alcoholic drink of your choosing.

Comment: So if my researching is correct, the user wouldn't even need FTP to pull the files down because they already have direct network file access to the server.  FTP is a mute point.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question. The question is about FTP. The answer is about a remote access using Windows PowerShell. Those are two completely unrelated technologies. I'm aware that it has helped the OP, but that does not make the answer valid. The answer should at least mention, that it uses a different technology that the OP has asked for.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - Well, the answer is that "FTP does not do that." Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by "FTP does not do that"?

Comment: The OP question is how to move a file on the remote server to another location on the remote server. I do not find a mv, cp, move, copy, or other related FTP command that would do that. Is there one?

Comment: No, the OP question is *"Batch file to move files **from** one **FTP** folder to another folder in the same FTP?"* - i..e *"FTP"* specifically, not *"remote server"* in general. And yes, there's FTP command for that. My answer shows that.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - Ok. I was afraid that `rename` was a Windows only or a WinSCP only thing. Apparently, it is not.

Comment: @L.Moy - Feel free to select Martin Prikryl's answer as the best one.